# How can i add texture with a realistic fabric look to my mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, opengl

I've created a mesh in blender and am trying to add a material in a way that will give the model a realistic fabric look.

I added a material with an image texture, but the model looks very smooth and unrealistic far from a cloth like/fabric look.

Please how can i achieve this? (is it the image am using or i will have to update some properties in the node editor?)

Secondly, the end goal is to export the model as .obj/.mtl file and import/render it in an AR app using opengl es, so the key is to be able to retain the look in the app, please which method/approach is the best....how do i go about it?
Thanks.

Comment: Try a PBR material: https://www.textures.com/browse/pbr-materials/114558

Comment: maybe share a part of your fabric picture so that we can try a material

Comment: @FFeller Thanks for your reply, i think some of the materials there were created using substance painter. I know there's a way to
to use substance painter materials in blender, but can i read it via opengl and attach it to my mesh? since my main goal is to render the model
in my android app

Comment: @moonboots thanks for your reply, here's the link https://imgur.com/a/mknr7n2 its an african fabric style

Answer (score 1):

There must be a lot of solutions to make a fabric material but here is one that doesn't look too bad:

- First find a fabric texture and make it tileable, if it's not already. Convert it to a Normal map and a Specularity map with a software like CrazyBump or else.
- Build your node organization as below.
- Increase the *Scale* in he *Mapping* node so that the texture is repeated.
- Mix a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*, use the Specularity as factor, it will make the threads shine a bit.
- Plug the *Normal* map to both the *Diffuse* and *Glossy* to give a bit of 3D relief to the whole thing.
- Then, as a fabric might shine a bit like velvet, bring a second *Mix* shader and use a *Fresnel*.
- Now you just need to plug your colored pattern in the yellow socket of the *Diffuse*.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your time, i will give this a shot now. However i got some clarifications i would like you to help me with
The process in step 2 to 7 is an option to doing it in CrazyBump right?

Comment: i think my reference image (https://imgur.com/a/mknr7n2) is not 100% tileable how do you suggest i make it seamless, edit it?

Comment: i read somewhere that node editor settings are specific to the renderer, and blender doesnt export this
(https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)
are you sure this setup will be exported and take effect when i read the material and render in model opengl?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about CrazyBump, if you want to give your fabric a fake 3D relief you need to create a Normal or Bump map, with CrazyBump or this sort of software. About your reference image: you only need to make it tileable if you want it to be repeated on the fabric, if it's only displayed once you don't need. And for the last question I'm sorry I don't know a lot about export  :/

Comment: Oh I get you now, you gave me two options to give it a Bump map...i.e either with crazy bump or by building my node organisation as you stated, I will try that. About the export I will try it for myself and see... seeing is believing ...Thanks @moonboots

Comment: no, you don't understand, for this node setup, you need 2 image textures that are 2 maps: one normal map and one specular map. To generate normal or specular maps from a picture you need a software like CrazyBump or else. Then when you have your maps you open them in the Image Texture nodes and plug these nodes into what there are supposed to be plugged (here Normal Map node and the factor of a Mix Shader)

Comment: Waoh, thanks so much for the breakdown...sorry i'm an android developer trying to build basic model for my AR app ‍♂️ (with little knowledge on 3D/blender). Thanks once again.

Comment: A quick one, can designing a fabric like image in Photoshop work? And also PBR materials with a software like Surface painter is another option too right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "designing a fabric like image", but one thing I didn't tell you is that to make a pattern repeatable you can use a filter in photoshop: Go on the top menu > Filter > Other > Offset, play with the parameters and use the clone stamp tool to help making the picture repeatable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91670/discussion-between-distjoy-and-moonboots).